# How to merge mutiple tables into one, with same schema and column names

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 collection datatable that shows in this below

```
Month: January
ID     NAME       Absent
001    John       3
002    Travis     0

Month: February
ID     NAME       Absent
001    John       18
002    Travis     14

Month: March
ID     NAME       Absent
001    John       10
002    Travis     5
```

**Before**, I have used to `merge` DataTable

```
dataTable.merge(dataTable2);
```

The result is like this:

```
ID     NAME       Absent
001    John       3
002    Travis     0
001    John       18
002    Travis     14
001    John       10
002    Travis     5

dataTable.Merge(dataTableTemp);
GridView.DataSource = dataTable;
GridView.DataBind();
```

**But, I want to create like this** (we say: custom GridView):

```
               Jan      Feb     Mar    Apr
ID    NAME     Absent   Absent  Absent Absent
001   John     3        18      10
002   Travis   0        14      5
```

How to add/merge every month in the right side of table before, so if I add next month it will appear in the right side of table before..

How to create this:??? Is there any method of function or tools that I can use??

Thanks for any help..

Comment: Is the name or number of the month available in your original table? That would make things easier... (rather than having to figure out from sequence, which entry is which month)

Comment: How is SharePoint related to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
        void Merge(DataTable masterDataTable, DataTable[] dataTables, int columnIndex)
        {
            foreach (DataTable dt in dataTables)
            {
                DataColumn newColumn = masterDataTable.Columns.Add(dt.TableName, typeof(int));
                int newColumnIndex = masterDataTable.Columns.IndexOf(newColumn);
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    masterDataTable.Rows[i][newColumnIndex] = dt.Rows[i][columnIndex];
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is how you use it:

```
       Merge( janDataTable, new DataTable[]{ febDataTable, marDataTable, aprDataTable}, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot your table. Take a look at this:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/articles/5091.aspx